# Samsung AOD and lock screen media metadata Unknown

Tags: android

I do have my own application for media playback - it's using `MediaSessionCompat` (with combination with `ExoPlayer` and it's `MediaSessionConnector` plugin).

On Samsung phone I experience a small issue with AOD (Always On Display) and  lock screen.  Both contains a small media controller (three buttons) and track title and album -  I assume it works with MediaSession.

My problem is that it always shows Unknown / Unknown for title / album (but buttons are working correctly).  I'm sure that I'm feeding correctly MediaSession metadata, as it is used in Activities, where using `onMetadataChange` callback and it contains correct title.

I'm somehow lost, not sure where to look for issue and fix. It's clearly in my app, because other players are working fine (showing title on AOD), but I do not know what else I need to do apart of settings metadata in MediaSession?

Answer (score 9):

So shortly

Exoplayer uses `MediaDescriptionCompat` to get meta from play queue.  Then it maps it to `MediaMetadataCompat`  and title is mapped to key `MEDIA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE` , where Samsung is using key `MEDIA_KEY_TITLE` only. 
Solution was to add `MEDIA_KEY_TITLE` to `MediaDescriptionCompat.extras`.

Another item displayed in Samsung AOD, lock screen is `MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST`

Another example of useless complexity in Android - why we need to two classes for metadata, which are almost the same `MediaMetadataCompat` vs `MediaDescriptionCompat`?

Comment: @murtadhaalsabbagh  - check this issue on exoplayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4292

Comment: How to add it , could you please share example

Answer (score 3):

[@Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720030/ivan)'s answer worked for me. Here is an example in Kotlin:

```
   mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession).also {
        it.setPlayer(player)
    }
    mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(object : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession){
        override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
            val extra = Bundle()
            extra.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "podcastEpisode")
            return MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder().setExtras(extra).setTitle("podcastTitle").build()
        }
    })
```

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144878/media-session-has-no-title-on-aod-always-on-display) was also very helpful.

Comment: I was setting metadata on the media session instance, but it was showing unknown / not provided while switching videos. The `setQueueNavigator` allowed me to define a "loading" placeholder for such state.